# How to stop old click event and start a new one

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please check out this code: http://jsfiddle.net/XNnHC/4270/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#close-btn").hide();
    var slider_width = $('.pollSlider').width(); //get width automaticly
    $('#pollSlider-button').click(function() {
        if ($(this).css("margin-right") == slider_width + "px" && !$(this).is(':animated')) {
            $('.pollSlider,#pollSlider-button').animate({
                "margin-right": '-=' + slider_width
            }); 
            $("#close-btn").hide();
        } else {
            if (!$(this).is(':animated')) //perevent double click to double margin
            {
                $('.pollSlider,#pollSlider-button').animate({
                    "margin-right": '+=' + slider_width
                });
                $("#close-btn").show(500);
                $("#pollSlider-button").css({
                    'cursor': "default"
                });
                // pointer over the close button
                $("#close-btn").css({
                    'cursor': "pointer"
                });
            }
        }
   });
});
```

I am having trouble to figure out how to switch to "close button" in order to be able to animate slider from right to left, after first animation has been completed. Currently close button doesnt have its function, and slider only works if it has been clicked on pollSlider-button, in both ways. I have been digging over the internet, trying methods such as off.unbind('click'),preventDefault and stopPropagation, however I have not accomplished much, I assume I havent put code on the right place. Since I am JS and JQuery beginner, and since I have found this code and have been working on it to adapt it to my own needs, I have realized I dont really know what does this part of the code refer to: "`$(this)`". I can see that `alert($(this).css("margin-right"))` returns 0px before and 200px after animation, but I dont understand to what element is connected to. Any explanation would really be appriciated and deeper understanding could lead to soloving issue above.

Comment: Just set a global variable that indicates which direction the animation should go, and use that variable in the click handler.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, have no idea how to do that. I am ears if you have will to show me.

Comment: $(this) refers to the button with id 'pollSlider-button' in this context.

Comment: Actually, after looking at your fiddle, I think I misunderstood the question. I'm not sure why you need to switch anything on the close button, since it's not even visible until they do the animation.

Comment: @CaptainMagikarp I assumed that, but I have no idea what is relation between pollSlider-button and 0px and 200px, except it represents trigger: http://jsfiddle.net/XNnHC/4271/. For example. this is clear to me: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_click.

Comment: @Barmar well I have exact same code like this, exept I am using image as trigger. So I want to be able to close slider after close button is showed on image, and prevent clicking on image itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to have the "X" close it when its clicked. One option would be to put your close functionality in its own function and call it when that X is clicked. So you could do something like:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XNnHC/4275/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Cache the close button so only have to lookup once
  var closeBtn = $("#close-btn");
  closeBtn.hide();
  var slider_width = $('.pollSlider').width(); //get width automaticly

  $('#pollSlider-button').click(function() {

    if ($(this).css("margin-right") != slider_width + "px" && !$(this).is(':animated')) //perevent double click to double margin
    {
      $('.pollSlider,#pollSlider-button').animate({
        "margin-right": '+=' + slider_width
      });
      closeBtn.show(500).css({
        'cursor': "pointer"
      });;

      $("#pollSlider-button").css({
        'cursor': "default"
      });
    }

  });

  // Close function
  closeBtn.on('click', function() {
    $('.pollSlider,#pollSlider-button').animate({
      "margin-right": '-=' + slider_width
    });
    closeBtn.hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: thnx for your reply. same reply to the answer above. I also want to be able to prevent event if you click on the pollSlider-button after first animation. So I just want only to be able to close slider if I click on close button.

Comment: Updated. You can get rid of your first if statement and add the same margin check within the slide if statement, but check to see if its not equal.If its not equal, that means it should slide. And then only add your close functionality when the close button is clicked. Fiddle updated as well.

Answer (score 0):

just add close-button on the listener and replace $(this) :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#close-btn").hide();
  var slider_width = $('.pollSlider').width(); //get width automaticly
  $('#pollSlider-button').on('click',open);

  function open(){
    if (!$('#pollSlider-button').is(':animated')) //perevent double click to double margin
    {

    $('.pollSlider,#pollSlider-button').animate({
    "margin-right": '+=' + slider_width
    });
    $("#close-btn").show(500);

    $("#pollSlider-button").css({
    'cursor': "default"
    });
    // pointer over the close button
    $("#close-btn").css({
    'cursor': "pointer"
    });
    }
    $('#pollSlider-button').off();
    $('#close-btn').on('click',close);
  };
  
  function close(){
    $('.pollSlider,#pollSlider-button').animate({
    "margin-right": '-=' + slider_width
    });
    $("#close-btn").hide(); 
    $('#pollSlider-button').on('click',open);
  };
});
```

```css
.pollSlider{
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
    width:200px;
    right:0px;
    margin-right: -200px;
}
#pollSlider-button{
    position:fixed;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    right:0px;
    background:green;
    top:300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pollSlider"></div>
<div id="pollSlider-button"></div>

<i class="fa fa-times fa-5x" id="close-btn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: thnx for your reply. I also want to be able to prevent event if you click on the pollSlider-button after first animation. So I just want only to be able to close slider if I click on close button.

Comment: in this case just create two separated functions and prefer use `on('click',function(){});` rather than `click(function(){});` this way you can remove easyly event listener with `off();` and add them when you desire. I edit the snippet to have the desired behavior

Comment: thanks for explanation. but I must note!  I have tried to run your code snippet, what happens is that pollSlider disapperars after second time pressing close button